# How to read inconsistency tag in SOAP response

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

There is inconsistency in the tag  ,I am not having idea how to read this kind of SOAP message.Usually I try reading SOAP response by reflection mechanism mentioned below.But I will not be able to read all the tags with this.
How to read this kind of SOAP response in java ?

```
   SOAP Response :      
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://">
           <soap:Body>
              <ns2:getIResponse xmlns:ns2="http://">
                 <response>
                    <EC>0</EC>

                    <Actions>
                       <Actions>
                          <Code>368777</sapCode>
                          <skuBarcode>3378872096214</skuBarcode>
                          <itemId>14</itemId>
                          <description>abcdedf</description>
                          <value>100</value>
                          <rLimit>5</rLimit>
                          <rCount>0</rCount>
                          <lCount>5</lCount>
                       </Actions>
                       <Actions>
                          <Code>368801</Code>
                          <skuBarcode>3378878314176</skuBarcode>
                          <itemId>17</itemId>
                          <description>10 Off/description>
                          <value>300</value>
                          <rCount>0</rCount>
                       </Actions>
                       <Actions>
                          <Code>420531</Code>
                          <skuBarcode>3378878362962</skuBarcode>
                          <itemId>391</itemId>
                          <description>abcdefgh</description>
                          <value>500</value>
                          <rLimit>5</rLimit>
                          <rCount>0</rCount>
                          <lCount>5</lCount>
                       </Actions>
                    </Actions>
                 </response>
              </ns2:getIResponse>
           </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

##There is inconsistency in the tag  ,I am not having idea how to read this kind of SOAP message.Usually I try reading SOAP response by refection mechanism mentioned below.But I will not be able to read all the tags with this.##

```
    public static ArrayList readResponse(String response, Object output) throws Exception {
            Class<? extends Object> theClass = output.getClass();
            Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();
            boolean successResponse = false;
            InfoRes InfoRes=new InfoRes();
            ArrayList<InfoRes> alInfoRes = new ArrayList<Res>();


            for (int i=0;i<fields.length; i++) {
                Type type = fields[i].getType();
                fields[i].setAccessible(true);

                String tag = "<" + fields[i].getName().toLowerCase() + ">";
                String strValue = "";

                if(response.toLowerCase().contains(tag)) {
                    strValue = response.substring(response.toLowerCase().indexOf(tag) + tag.length(),
                            response.toLowerCase().indexOf("</" + fields[i].getName().toLowerCase() + ">"));
                    successResponse = true;
                }

                //Set value
                if(type.equals(String.class)) {
                    if(! strValue.isEmpty())
                        fields[i].set(output, strValue);
                }
                else if(type.equals(Integer.TYPE) || type.equals(Integer.class)) {
                    if(! strValue.isEmpty())
                        fields[i].setInt(output, Integer.valueOf(strValue));
                }
                else if(type.equals(Date.class)) { 
                    if(! strValue.isEmpty()) {
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        fields[i].set(output, format.parse(strValue));
                    }
                }
                else if(type.equals(Long.TYPE) || type.equals(Long.class)) {
                    if(! strValue.isEmpty())
                        fields[i].setLong(output, Long.valueOf(strValue));
                }
            }
```

"Expected  Result:"

Code : 368777
skuBarcode : 3378872096214 
itemId : 14 
Description :  F Filler 
Value : 100 
rlimit : 5 
rCount : 0 
lCount : 5

----------

Code : 368801 
skuBarcode : 3378878314176 
itemId : 17  
Description : 10% Off 
Value : 300 
rCount : 0 
---------------- 
Code : 420531 
skuBarcode : 3378878362962 
itemId : 391 
description :   Addiction Set 
Value : 500 
rlimit : 5 
rCount : 0 
lCount : 5

Comment: What kind inconsistency that you mean? Please explain more about your problem

Comment: If you see <Actions> tag and its sub tags <rCount>0</rCount> is not available in second  set of tag ,also this tag count of response may not be same for all the request. I need to read each <Actions> tag values separately .

Comment: edited the question with expected result .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your soap api have a WSDL? if so you can use this when you have intellij https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-java-code-from-wsdl-or-wadl-dialog.html or if you use eclipse http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html you'll get java code, which is much easier to work with :-)

Comment: It is not a scratch level project that I can generate client code to work with .Any other idea please ?

Comment: Can anyone respond to this ?Please